# Spring Integration Java DSL HTTP no reply received within timeout error

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I am using Spring integration 5.0.6. I have gone though it's document and created following code which listens on a HTTP endpoint and publish to a kafka topic.

Everything is working fine and I am receiving message at topic also. But at HTTP client there is no reply sent, it's giving "No reply received within timeout".

**How can I send a reply back to http caller in below code:**

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel replyChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean(name = "restInputFlow")
public IntegrationFlow send() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/push").requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
                    .requestPayloadType(String.class).replyChannel(replyChannel()))
            .transform(new Transformer())
            .handle(kafkaMessageHandler(producerFactory(), getKafkaSourceTopic()))
            .enrichHeaders(
                    c -> c.header(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, HttpStatus.CREATED))
            .get();
}

private KafkaProducerMessageHandlerSpec<GenericRecord, GenericRecord, ?> kafkaMessageHandler(
            ProducerFactory<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> producerFactory, String topic) {

        return Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(producerFactory)
                .messageKey("key").headerMapper(mapper())
                .topicExpression("headers[kafka_topic] ?: '" + topic + "'")
                .configureKafkaTemplate(t -> t.id("kafkaTemplate:" + topic));
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that you use a one-way `Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(producerFactory)`. This is just for "send-and-forget".

If you are interested in producing some subsequent process or just as you need to reply to the HTTP request, you should consider to use a:

```
/**
 * The {@link org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel} {@link #channel}
 * method specific implementation to allow the use of the 'subflow' subscriber capability.
 * @param publishSubscribeChannelConfigurer the {@link Consumer} to specify
 * {@link PublishSubscribeSpec} options including 'subflow' definition.
 * @return the current {@link IntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 */
public B publishSubscribeChannel(Consumer<PublishSubscribeSpec> publishSubscribeChannelConfigurer) {
```

On the flow definition, where your first subscriber is really going to be that  `Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(producerFactory)` and the second one can be that mentioned `.enrichHeaders()`. If you do nothing more, this last one is going to send its result into the `replyChannel` header and, therefore, will reach an HTTP response.

In this publish-subscribe scenario you should keep in mind that the `payload` for the second subscriber is going to be the same you try to send to Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Artem. After transform(), I replaced code with this one: `.publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c
      .subscribe(sf -> sf.handle(kafkaMessageHandler(producerFactory(),
        getKafkaSourceTopic())))
      .subscribe(sf -> sf.enrichHeaders(msg -> msg.header(
        org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, HttpStatus.CREATED))))
    .get();`  But now it's showing exception: no output-channel or replyChannel header available.

Comment: I think you have some issue in the `.transform(new Transformer())`. If you create your own `Message` there, you should copy request headers as well.